# Inhomogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I shall solve an inhomogeneous recurrence relation:
$$x_n=2x_{n-1}+2^n,\quad x_0=2$$
My approach:

The homogeneous part:
$$x_n=2x_{n-1}\implies x_n-2x_{n-1}=0$$ 
With $x_n=x^n$ approach:
$$x^n-2x^{n-1}=0$$
The characteristic equation has the form:
$$x-2=0\implies x_0=2$$
The recurrence looks like this:
$$x_n=c*2^n$$
Find the coefficient c:
$$2^0*c=x_0\implies c=x_0\implies c=2$$
So the corresponding homogeneous recursion has the form:
$$x_n=2*2^n=2^{n+1}$$

The inhomogeneous part is of the form $x_n=a*2^n$:
Plugging this into recursion gives the equation:
$$a*2^n=2*(a*2^{n-1})+2^n\implies a2^n=a2^n+2^n$$
Divided by $2^n$ gives:
$$a=a+1$$
And that's wrong.
I've tried to solve the problem a couple of times, cause I thought I was doing some of the calculations wrong... Now I'm just lost and have no idea how to grasp this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_{np}$ a particular solution for the recurrence relation. Since the recurrence relations is of the form $g(n)=a^n$, then $x_{np}=qa^n$ except if $a$ is solution for the characteristic equation with multiplicity $s$, in which case $x_{np}=qn^sa^n$.

It was your error: 2 is solution for the caracteristic equation, which is $x-2=0$, with multiplicity $s=1$. Then, the particular solution is of the form $x_{np}=qn2^n$.

Now you can continue.